# /bin/sh: /bin/cp: Argument list too long

Tags: find, directory, cp

I have problem with this command:

```
 'cp' -fr /www/*-aws/* /www/mainhost/aws/awstatstotals/tmp/
```

Error is **Argument list too long** - I know many /www/*-aws/* folders. I know that I can use FIND command, but I dont know how I can give two wildcard as folder paramater. Can you help me please?

Thank you Pavel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put wildcards in the folder parameter. Put them in the path parameter.

```
find /www -maxdepth 2 -path '*-aws/*' -exec cp -frt /www/mainhost/aws/awstatstotals/tmp/ {} +
```

Comment: You probably want to use `-exec cp -fr {} +` so that cp is invoked with a full command line.

Comment: Thank you! but little mistake: find /www -path '*-aws/*' -maxdepth 1
find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -path, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.- + right depth is 2

Comment: Oops, never seen that warn before. I included maxdepth so cp doesn't blow up when recursing--guess I need to watch the order. Added '+' per @Iain 's suggestion.

Comment: Huh, tried to run with + and a trailing destination per the suggestion. find doesn't like that, so I removed it. If someone wants to edit it so + works, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Edited. To use `+` you must also use `cp -t` so you can put the target directory first.